# rtrim fails with very long strings

Tags: php, trim

I'm building a very large query string, (8000 raws, using it only once in a million years.) I need to get rid of the final comma, which is added while the string is being built.

Take a look at my code, for some reason it as if `rtrim()` does nothing to it; the
string passed into `rtrim()` returns completely intact.

(If you need a copy of the value of query_string value, let me know and I'll upload it too.)

```
public function sync_sites_table()
{

    # $query_string = "TRUNCATE TABLE " . self::$table_name;
    # $db->query($query_string);

    $this->build_sites_object();

    $query_string = "INSERT INTO `".self::$table_name . "` (`site_id`, `site_name`) VALUES \n";

    foreach($this->sites_array as $key => $value)
    {
        $query_string .= "('".$key."','".$value."'), \n";
    }

    rtrim($query_string, ",");

    global $db;
    $db->query($query_string);

}
```

Comment: Is it an issue that your string ends with `, \n`, and you're just telling rtrim to remove a trailing `,`? Because there's not going to be a comma at the end.

Comment: Posting your query string could help, yes. If it's *too* long, you could post it in a pastebin site.

Comment: @andrewsi I thought so as well, but removing it didn't help.

Comment: @elad.chen - removing what didn't help? Also, have a look at my answer and see if either suggestion there helps.

Comment: try `rtrim(rtrim($data), ",");`

Comment: @AmalMurali Here it is: http://pastebin.com/k6Wr4z6i I have changed the values in order to avoid exposing the actual sites due to confidential obligations.

Comment: @Orangepill Thanks, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: rtrim() isn't pass by reference; it ___returns___ the trimmed value which you need to assign to a variable: `$query_string = rtrim($query_string, ",");`

Comment: The answer was keeping the code posted in my question as it, all that I needed to do was catch the value rtrim returned. Thanks :)

Comment: @MarkBaker You should post that as the answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rtrim() isn't pass by reference; it returns the trimmed value which you need to assign to a variable:

```
$query_string = rtrim($query_string, ",");
```

But a cleaner answer might be:

```
$first = true;
foreach($this->sites_array as $key => $value)
{
    if (!$first) { $query_string .= ', '; } else { $first = false; }
    $query_string .= "('".$key."','".$value."') \n";
}
```

so you wouldn't need to trim any trailing `,`

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the cleaner way. Where / When does first value change?

Comment: In the first iteration, $first is set to true; so the code sets $first to false, and appends the key/value to your query string; in subsequent iterations, $first is always false, so the code adds a comma before appending the key/value to your query string. It means you'll never have a trailing comma that needs removing

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `substr($query_string,0,-1)` instead of `rtrim($query_string, ",");`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($this->sites_array as $key => $value)
{
    $query_string .= "('".$key."','".$value."'), \n";
}

rtrim($query_string, ",");
```

The second parameter for rtrim is a list of characters you want stripping from the end of the string. But the string you're generating will always terminate in `, \n` - there's no trailing comma. You can try:

```
rtrim($query_string, ", \n");
```

Which should work; but it might be more elegant to do:

```
$params = array();

foreach($this->sites_array as $key => $value)
{
    $params[] = "('".$key."','".$value."')";
}

$query_string .= implode (",", $params);
```

Comment: I was aware of this solution, however I'm trying to to figure out why rtrim fails..

Comment: ... I still think using implode is neater, though :D

Comment: Performance wise would the implode solution be faster then rtrim?

Comment: I suspect it'll be slightly less efficient - you're building an array, instead of populating a string, and then joining it together at the end; so you'll be using more memory and it'll probably take a little longer. But unless you're talking about huge datasets, I don't think the performance difference would be noticeable.

Comment: That's what I thought :)

Comment: Performance wise it all depends how many key/value pairs you have in your sites array

Answer (score 0):

Although this has been asked 3 years ago, I still think it might be useful to answer.

Having recently encountered the same issue processing a 70Mb size string, for me it was solved by temporary increase php's ini setting `memory_limit`.

So you can use `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')` or change your php.ini file for a more permanent solution.

Ps. setting `memory_limit` to -1 won't limit php memory usage, but use with caution.

more on memory_limit: 
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit